# Rotate div with It's Content Issue

Tags: html, css, rotation, css-transforms

I would like to make **continuous div - vertical orientation with its content** `using CSS`. So i used transform: rotation() method. If I have used the following code, its get Overlapped.

**Input:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type='text/css'>
    .container{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
        -moz-transform-origin: left top;
        -ms-transform-origin: left top;
        -o-transform-origin: left top;
        transform-origin: left top;
        margin:10px;
        background-color:#ffceff;       
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='container '>
       <span>Rotate Me</span>
    </div>
    <div class='container '>
       <span>Rotate Me</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image: div rotation]

**Expected Output:**
[image: expected div]

Could anybody suggest the solution for this?

**Note:**

If I use `display: inline-block`, then its not overlapping but the space which is the width of the container is occupying between container after rotation.

[image: display block]

Answer (score 2):

you need to put all the elements in a single container, and rotate this one

```css
    .container{
        -webkit-transform:  translateY(-100%) rotate(90deg) ;
        transform:  translateY(-100%) rotate(90deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
        transform-origin: left bottom;
        margin:10px;
        background-color:#ffceff;       
    }
```

```html
    <div class='container'>
      <div>
       <span>Rotate Me</span>
        </div>
      <div>
       <span>Rotate Me</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks. But without adding common container, i need to rotate the element.

Comment: @Ponmalar why? I think it's the best CSS solution.

Comment: You mean that the HTML can not be modified ? Then ... how many elements are there ? Is the width known / limited ?

Comment: yes HTML cannot be modified. Width will be changed dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, we have to add an "outer" tag and assign a width, the overflow data will be fixed with the withe-space: nowrap code, please try following code:

CSS:

```
.outer {
white-space: nowrap;
display: inline-block;
width: 20px;
}
.container {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
    -moz-transform-origin: bottom left;
    -ms-transform-origin: bottom left;
    -o-transform-origin: bottom left;
    transform-origin: bottom left 0px;
    margin:10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class='outer'>
    <div class='container' style="background-color: red;">
       <span>Rotate Measdadadadsasd</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class='outer'>
    <div class='container' style="background-color: blue;">
       <span>Rotate Me</span>
    </div>
</div>
```